# Dispose hook on widget rebuild

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod, flutter-hooks

Do hooks dispose of themselves when a widget rebuilds? Is it possible to cause this behavior?

I'm using Riverpod for state management and I have a widget that creates a custom `TextEditingController` hook in the build method. When I update my widget's state (in Riverpod) the widget correctly rebuilds but it seems to retain the old `TextEditingController` hook. Is it possible to automatically dispose of and recreate it?

Thanks!

Comment: Although hooks and riverpod are both from Remi, they are orthogonal: you can use either one or the other or both.  The only overlap is a small package to be able to ask for a StatefulHookConsumerWidget and get one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text controller will be disposed of as expected:

[image]

Therefore, nothing needs to be done.

Comment: Right, but does this change in a ListView? The widgets in the list rebuild but I noticed my text editing controller still retains previous things like listeners which should’ve been reset when the hook got disposed.

Comment: `ListView` will store everything. Try using `ListView.builder` to reset the state of non-visible widgets.

Comment: sorry that’s what I meant. I’m using the builder constructor which makes many widgets each with their own hook but for some reason those hooks persist

Comment: Got it, in this case add a key like `ValueKey` and try again

Comment: Ah, assigning a key worked. Thanks!